# NSOutlineView - Get NSTableCellView for a Given Item

Tags: macos, nsoutlineview, nstablecellview

My view-based outline view displays a custom context menu (right-click menu) for its rows.

One of the menu items on the menu is "Rename...", and the menu item's `representedObject` property is set to the object represented by the outline view row:

```
    let menu = NSMenu()

    // ...other menu items...

    let renameItem = NSMenuItem(
            title: "Rename...",
            action: #selector(OutlineViewController.rename(_:)),
            keyEquivalent: "")
    renameItem.representedObject = object

    menu.addItem(renameItem)
```

On the action side, I want to make the text field in the table cell editable, programmatically. The problem is, **I am not sure of how to get a reference to the table cell** from the represented object alone.

This is my action method:

```
@IBAction func rename(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let menuItem = sender as? NSMenuItem else { return }
    guard let item = menuItem.representedObject else { return }
```

I can get the row for the represented object (Int):

```
    let row = outlineView.row(forItem: item)
```

...and the row view (NSTableRowView):

```
    let rowView = outlineView.rowView(atRow: row, makeIfNecessary: false)
```

I can get the column index (Int) and column (NSTableColumn):

```
    let columnIndex = outlineView.column(withIdentifier: "TitleColumn")
    let column = outlineView.tableColumns[columnIndex]
```

...and attempt to get the cell view (NSTableCellView):

```
    guard let cell = outlineView(outlineView, viewFor: column, item: item) as? NSTableCellView else {
        return
    }
```

Finally, I try to make the text field editable:

```
    guard let textField = cell.textField else {
        return
    }
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

All these test pass (I set breakpoints), but nothing happens: The text field does **not** become editable (unlike when double clicking).

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

**Edit** I have realized that when I call:

```
outlineView(outlineView, viewFor: column, item: item)
```

This is basically the `NSOutlineViewDelegate` method that my view controller is implementing, so instead of giving me the cell already on screen, it is creating a new copy on demand. Kind of like calling

```
UITableViewController.tableView(_:,cellForRowAt:)
// Data source method, creates or dequeues a new cell to pass 
// back to the table for display
```

...instead of calling:

UITableView.cellForRowAt(_:)
   // Method of table view proper; returns existing cell if
   // already on screen, or defers to the data source (method 
   // above) otherwise

So instead of calling a delegate method that creates the cell view anew, I should query the outline view itself. However, the only meaningful method I can see is:

```
func rowView(atRow row: Int, makeIfNecessary: Bool) -> NSTableRowView?
```

...which returns an NSTable**Row**View...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved it**. Just had to dig a little deeper into the API:

```
// Get row index
let row = outlineView.row(forItem: item)

// Get view for the whole row: 
guard let rowView = outlineView.rowView(atRow: row, makeIfNecessary: false) else {
    return
}

// THIS is the missing piece: Get row subview for the given column
// (= cell)  
guard let cell = rowView?.view(atColumn: 0) as? NSTableCellView else {
    return
}
```

Now I have a reference to the actual text field already on screen, and it becomes editable:

```
self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(cell.textField)
```

Comment: Don't call `becomeFirstResponder`. "Use the NSWindow
makeFirstResponder(_:) method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.".

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, that’s what the docs say it seems. I wonder what harm can it cause. In iOS it’s common to call it directly on controls (but there is only one window!)

Comment: macOS ≠ iOS. Apple didn't say "Never invoke this method directly." just for fun.

Comment: @Willeke I don't understand what you are trying to say. The documentation for NSResponder.becomeFirstResponder() says: "Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder(_:) method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly."

Comment: Assume it can cause harm and don't do it.

Comment: Apple **did** say “Never invoke this method directly”.